# Cannot activate an already activated outlet .......I have updated my angular 12 project to angular 17 Im getting this err while navigate by using tab

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular17

## ERROR Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet

```
<kbd>your text</kbd>at IonRouterOutlet.activateWith (ionic-angular-common.mjs:1570:19)
at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (router.mjs:3108:40)
at router.mjs:3059:18
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (router.mjs:3058:29)
at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (router.mjs:3115:22)
at router.mjs:3059:18
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (router.mjs:3058:29)
at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (router.mjs:3110:26)
```

#this is  html

```
<ion-tab-button 
  class="custom-tab-bar"
  tab="tasksummary"
  (click)="$event.stopPropagation();TasktabClicked()"
>
  <!-- <ion-icon name="list-outline"></ion-icon> -->
  <ion-icon
    *ngIf="!tasktabClicked"
    src="assets/icon/task_tab.svg"
  ></ion-icon>
  <ion-icon
    *ngIf="tasktabClicked "
    src="assets/icon/task2_tab.svg"
  ></ion-icon>
  <ion-label [class.clicked]="tasktabClicked"
    >{{"Tasks" | translate :langEntType :langEntName :langChosen
    }}</ion-label
  >
</ion-tab-button>
```

#tabs-routing.module.ts

{
path: "tasksummary",
loadChildren: () =>
import("../tasksummary/tasksummary.module").then(
(m) => m.TasksummaryPageModule
),
},

#this is app-routing.module.ts

{
path: "tasksummary",
loadChildren: () =>
import("./pages/tasksummary/tasksummary.module").then(
(m) => m.TasksummaryPageModule
),
},